# Excluding URL in custom wordpress-angular application

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using *.htaccess* configuration to rewrite my routes, everything after `http://localhost:8080/loveat` is redirected to index.php where angular handles routing thanks to ui-routing. For example `http://localhost:8080/loveat/pricing`.

**The only url I don't want to rewrite is `http://localhost:8080/loveat/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=10&page=1` which is my json api.** I'm confused about apache configuration. Every time I type this url in, it fallbacks to angular and is handled by it. Where can I find proper configuration or proper tutorial on this topic?

.htaccess configuration:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [QSA,L]

# END WordPress
```

html5Mode is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you asked for it...[TAKE THIS](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html) **muhahahaha**

Ok, seriously, the Apache docs are REALLY good for getting a deeper understanding of rewrites.

In your specific case this should do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/loveat/wp-json/wp/v2/posts
RewriteRule . index.php [QSA,L]
```

That rewrites everything but URIs starting with `/loveat/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`

Comment: Thanks, To be honest I've read this doc and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/loveat/wp-json/wp/v2/posts` should work but it's not.

Here is picture after applying this configuration: http://imgur.com/V8K6ut4
Here is picture with vanilla wordpress configuration: http://imgur.com/zZjNePu.

Comment: I should add: My old config worked with "plain permalinks" wordpress option enabled and then json was disabled. With new config and "post name permalinks" enabled, json works, but my ui-router does not redirect properly.

Comment: You wrote `The only url I don't want to rewrite is http://localhost:8080/loveat/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=10&page=1 which is my json api.` but you just said/posted a picture that said that the ressoure wasn't found. So it seems like `/loveat/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=10&page=1` has also to be rewritten or myb you have to set a handler for this specific URI. But I don't know for sure since I have no idea how your JSON-api gets triggered...rewritewise the above solution should do what you asked for: rewrite everything to index.php except requests for json-api